# HTML Form doesn't work

Tags: php

Sorry, i have some problem.
In editor, I coding like this

```
<?php while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qr)) { ?>
    <form action="admin_search_save.php" method="POST">
        <tr>
            <td><?=$rs['firstname'].' '.$rs['lastname']?></td>
            <td><?=$rs['schoolof_id']?></td>
            <td><?=$rs['major_id']?></td>

            <input type="hidden" id="update" value="<?=$rs['id']?>">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid" placeholder="กรอกรหัสนักศึกษา" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">เลือก</option>
                    <option value="true">ชำระแล้ว</option>
                    <option value="false">ยังไม่ได้ชำระ</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"> </i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

But in chrome's console elements the code show like this
[image]

why is it not correlate?
I'm confusing.

Comment: you should put complete table inside form.

Comment: you should wrap the table with the form tag

Comment: I have many records, if,I put complete table inside form,I can not edit on each records.

Comment: u mean, multiple `form` tags in same page?

Comment: @user3726932 its possible to edit each row without having to have each form tags

Answer (score 2):

because you forget add table tag before tr

```
     <?php while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qr)) { ?>
            <form action="admin_search_save.php" method="POST">
                <table>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?=$rs['firstname'].' '.$rs['lastname']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rs['schoolof_id']?></td>
                    <td><?=$rs['major_id']?></td>

                    <input type="hidden" id="update" value="<?=$rs['id']?>">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid" placeholder="กรอกรหัสนักศึกษา" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">เลือก</option>
                            <option value="true">ชำระแล้ว</option>
                            <option value="false">ยังไม่ได้ชำระ</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"> </i>
                             บันทึก
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
            </form>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It's a comment more, than answer!

Comment: you need add table tag only once or check you have already added at first and last tr tag